# How to install Linux or boot USB with Windows 32Bit on UEFI and Atom

Tags: linux, windows, boot, uefi, atom-feed

I have some troubles with boot os install usb on funny toy called Kiano SlimNote 14.2. It's have CPU Intel Atom x5-Z8350, 2GB RAM small EMMC disk 30GB, UEFI and default installed Windows 10 64 bit. I would like to use this laptop to browsing the web, or reading some pdf in bed. But Windows 10 64bit is horrible producer decision. On this tiny disk always is not enough free space to do something. Otherwise, it works very slow.

So I made decision to replace this heavy OS with some linux, or Windows 32 bit. But I can't boot any USB Flash memory in Slimnote. I entered BIOS and change boot sequence, but with no effect. Always booting installed Win10 64bit.

Is it at all any way to boot linux on configuration like that? I would be grateful for any advices, tips or descriptions of simmilar situations from your lives.

Comment: There is a way but it's sort of complex. Among other tweaks it needs a special EFI 32-bit file to be added to the USB' s EFI folder. But don't waste your time because you won't be able to make work most of the devices in any Linux distro (WiFi, audio, etc.). The only supported OS for that cheap crappy CPU is the Windows you already have so, really make sure you can reinstall that one. Otherwise, your experiments will likely result in the "toy" becoming a brick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to install any OS yesterday, and after a lot of tries I have got one. I cant boot USB with Win10 32bit, Win7 32bit, Win7 64Bit, but at least I have succesfully installed Lubuntu 19.04 x64. As you (@GabrielaGarcia) said i copied EFI/boot/bootx64.efi to bootable pendrive and manually set partitions in OS instalation wizard. OS is running on this scrap, but I dont check drivers yesterday, because I finished battle with OS instalation very late. But final of this situation is an evidence that it is possible to install alternative OS on this heavy Win10 64bit place. I believe that problem with drivers will not appear, but if it happens I return to trying boot Win 32 bit. On official producer website is package with 32bit's drivers, robably predicted that it was possible. Well, we will see today. After work I'll resume to play with this Slimnote. Anyway thanks for tip. So We can conclude that the problem has been resolved.

EDIT: I checked drivers yesterday and everything looks okay. WiFi works, audio works too.